# I want to save ID itself included in the other data being saved

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-extensions

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvVsx.png)

I want to save the Room ID included to the Room Details in the right.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the room id first to set the data to that id, like this

```
 Future<void> addCategory(
    BuildContext context,
    String categoryName,
  ) async {
    bool hasConnection = await NetworkConn.isInternet();
    if (hasConnection) {
      String categoryId = category.doc().id;///this is the id
      return category.doc(categoryId).set({
        'id': categoryId,///this is the in feild 
        'CategoryName': categoryName,
        "AddedBy": user!.email,
        "CreatedAt: ": DateTime.now().toString(),
      }).then((value) {
        CustomDialog.showSuccessDialog(context, "Category Added");
      }).catchError((error) {
        Logger().e("Failed to add user: $error");
        CustomDialog.showErrorDialog(context, "Unable to add Category");
      });
    } else {
      CustomDialog.showErrorDialog(context, "Please Connect to Internet");
    }
  }
```